# Style / customize check boxes in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Take a look on attachement, how can I customize the check boxes in Sencha to look something like this? The biggest challenge is not probably the styling, but the possibility to have two checkboxes beside each other.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Dxup.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For styling, you can apply a cls property to the checkbox to add additional styling or use the baseCls property to wipe the st2 styling and apply your own... in order to get the checkboxes side by side you'll want to use a vbox layout in the parent container to accomplish that.. id offer sample code, but im on my mobile, let me know if you have questions and i can whip up an example for you tomorrow

Comment: Thanks for you reply, good points, I understood, you pointed me in right direction.